# Swift 2を使うとNSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()でコンパイルエラー 'Extra argument 'error' in call' が発生する

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Swift 1.2 では

```
var abc = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

の構文が通っていましたが、Swift 2 では

```
error: nil
```

の部分でエラーとなってしまします。
おそらく書き方が変わったのだと推測されますが、どのように書けば良いか または、それについて書いてある Reference の URL を教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2ではエラー処理の方法が変わり、新たに`ErrorType`、`do〜try〜catch`や`throw`という構文が導入されました。
それに合わせてObjective-Cにおいて`NSError`のダブルポインタを渡していたところは`try`構文を使って書くように変更されました。

**参考URL**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

これに従うと、ご提示のコードはSwift 2では、例えば下記のように変更する必要があります。

```
do {
    var abc = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

    // エラーが起こらなければ後続の処理...
} catch  {
    // エラーが起こったらここに来るのでエラー処理などをする
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
書かれたコードを試した所、正常に動作しました。
また、URL まで掲載していただきありがとうございます。
理解が深まりました。